# pygame having trouble with wasd keybinding

Tags: python, pygame

trying to do a dumb little begginer game and i wanted to have two players, one using arrow keys and one using wasd, arrows are working with no issue but i have no idea how to do wasd, i apologize in advance im a begginer in python and my names are in portuguese so before i send the code let me just help out in saying that im using "jogador1" and "jogador2" to mean "player1" and "player2"

here's the full code

````
# jogo plataformer 1
import pygame
# começar o programa
pygame.init()
# ecrã
ecrã = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Trump attack")
backgroundImg = pygame.image.load("weirdbackground.png")
def background():
    ecrã.blit(backgroundImg, (0, 0))
funcionar = True
# loop do jogo
# jogador1
jogadorImg =pygame.image.load("biden1.png")
jogadorX = 282
jogadorY = 58
jogadorX_mudar = 0
jogadorY_mudar = 0
# jogador2
jogador2Img = pygame.image.load("trump1.png")
jogador2X = 436
jogador2Y = 58
jogador2Y_mudar = 0
jogador2X_mudar = 0
# bala do jogador 1
balaImg = pygame.image.load("trump2.png")
balaX = jogadorX
balaY = int(jogadorY - 5)
balaY_mudar = 0
balaX_mudar = 0
bala_estado = "pronto"
def disparar(x, y):
    global bala_estado
    bala_estado = "fire"
    ecrã.blit(balaImg, (balaX, balaY))
def jogador2(x, y):
    ecrã.blit(jogador2Img, (x, y))
def jogador(x, y):
    ecrã.blit(jogadorImg, (x, y))
while funcionar:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            funcionar = False
    # keybinds jogador 1
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            jogadorX_mudar = -1
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            jogadorX_mudar = 1
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            jogadorY_mudar =-1
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            jogadorY_mudar = 1
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            disparar(balaX, balaY)
            print("hello")
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            jogadorX_mudar = 0
    if jogadorY < -30:
        jogadorY_mudar += 1
    if jogadorY == float(231.0):
        jogadorY_mudar *= 0
        jogadorY -= 1
    #keybinds jogador 2
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            jogador2X_mudar = -1
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            jogador2X_mudar = 1
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            jogador2Y_mudar =-1
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            jogador2Y_mudar = 1
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            jogador2X_mudar = 0
    if jogador2Y < -30:
        jogador2Y_mudar += 1
    if jogador2Y == float(231.0):
        jogador2Y_mudar *= 0
        jogador2Y -= 1
    # bloco de cima jogador1
    if (jogadorY <=200 and jogadorY >= 45) and (jogadorX >= 227 and jogadorX <= 448):
        jogadorY_mudar *= 0
    if (jogadorY <= 45) and (jogadorX >= 448 or jogadorX <= 227):
        jogadorY_mudar += 1
    # bloco de cima jogador2
    if (jogador2Y <=200 and jogador2Y >= 45) and (jogador2X >= 227 and jogador2X <= 448):
        jogador2Y_mudar *= 0
    if (jogador2Y <= 45) and (jogador2X >= 448 or jogador2X <= 227):
        jogador2Y_mudar += 1
    if bala_estado == "fire":
        disparar(balaX, balaY)
        balaY += 1
    background()
    jogadorX += jogadorX_mudar
    jogadorY += jogadorY_mudar
    jogador2Y += jogador2Y_mudar
    jogador2X += jogador2X_mudar
    jogador2(jogador2X, jogador2Y)
    jogador(jogadorX, jogadorY)
    pygame.display.update()
    ```
````

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html ?

Comment: yeah but even using K_a for left or K_d for right, etc it doesnt work for some reason.

Comment: that's weird, have you tried printing something on those key presses to see if the issue is with the keypress being registered or something else?

Comment: yeah on this code i sent i even kept in the print command on k_a, the thing that stuns me is that the "jogador1" aka player1 works, with arrow keys, but the exact same copy pasted code changed to "jogador2" with K_a and K_d etc isn't printing or moving. I could send the entire code if thats any help.

Comment: Could you post the full code to try it?

Comment: updated to have the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The events must be handled **in** the event loop, instead of **after** the event loop:

```py
while funcionar:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            funcionar = False

    # INDENTQTION
    #-->|
        # keybinds jogador 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                jogadorX_mudar = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                jogadorX_mudar = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                jogadorY_mudar =-1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                jogadorY_mudar = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                disparar(balaX, balaY)
                print("hello")
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                jogadorX_mudar = 0

    #[...]
```